# How to calculate the percentage of total that meet a certain condition in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, count, apache-spark, sum, apache-spark-sql

Considering the following data:

```
Name | Value
-----|------
A    |  0
A    | 15
A    |  5
B    |  3
B    | 10
B    | 12
```

I'd like to transform it to:

```
Name | Total | With Value >= 10 | Percentage
-----|-------|------------------|-----------
A    | 3     | 1                | 33%
B    | 3     | 2                | 66%
```

Preferably, in Spark SQL.

Remark: in my real case, the Value is an array and I'd like to know the percentage of those that have a non-empty array.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: If your "Value" column is an array, then how have you considered transforming your dataframe in order to be queried? Regardless of that, the query that you can use to create the output that you want is the one from my answer, the only per-requisite is that your array is a table with one value per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark SQL is just regular SQL, albeit with limited SQL functionalities, so you could just write a regular query, like the one below:

```
SELECT
    NAME
    , COUNT(*) AS Total
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "With Value >= 10"
    , (COUNT(*) * 1.0 /SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100
FROM <table>
GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: I think it requires `count(1)` instead of `count(*)`, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @BreakPhreak It shouldn't make a difference, both are fine. Actually, in some RDBMS systems it's preferred to use `COUNT(*)` and runs faster, but I don't think Spark uses them same engine.